# Modifying values in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, string

I have an array with string values. I want to add additional text before or after each value in the array. How can I do this?

From what I have seen I am guessing it will be something like:

```
$.each(array, function() {
   // something here
});
```

Everything I have tried doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What what _did_ you try?

Comment: If you look at [the documentation for the function you're trying to use](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), you'll see that the handler conveniently receives both the array index and value of the element under iteration. **Always read the documentation when you're not sure about a function that you're trying to use.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use plain JavaScript, that runs a little bit faster.

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
 array[i] = 'some text ' + array[i] + ' some other text';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think in this case it's easier not to use jQuery, since jQuery returns the values too (and you're actually only looking for the numeric keys).

Comment: Yup. Worked beautifully. I was overcomplicating it. :)

Comment: @Tim: Well, not quite. You _do_ use the values!

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.  Try:

```
$.each(array, function(i, v){
   array[i] = array[i] + 'hello';
});
```

You could also use map:

```
var newArray = $.map(array, function(v, i) {
   return v + 'hello';
});
```